# Execute SQLs in Parallel from directory

Tags: multithreading, powershell, t-sql

I am able to execute all the .SQL files from directory on to the server serially using below command. But, we want to execute all these files in parallel.

My code for serial execution -

```
$PSScriptRoot = 'Y:\test\'

$ServerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME 


foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem -path $PSScriptRoot -Filter *.sql | sort-object 
-desc ) 
{ 
 invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $f.fullname -ServerInstance $ServerName 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jobs to have them execute in the background:

```
foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem -path $PSScriptRoot -Filter *.sql | sort-object 
-desc) 
{ 
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { invoke-sqlcmd -InputFile $args[0].fullname -ServerInstance $args[1] } -ArgumentList $f, $ServerName
}
```

If there is any output you can collect it via:

```
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark.. It worked.. Wonderful!! Thanks again.